# MultiUser login in a single facebook app

Tags: c#, facebook

I am creating a application in C# that uses face recognition as authentication method,after logging in it gets detail from the user's facebook  account.

If first user just locks the app instead of logging out from facebook,another user comes in ,do i have to logout the first user for the second user to log in ,or i can login both users in a single app?Is it possible using the facebook sdk?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use session to keep track of various users who are logging in.

In short, you can have multiple users logged in at the same time, if you implement session correctly.

Comment: Thanks Neelesh! I am new to facebook sdk.How to create sessions using facebook sdk?